# Trying to get a startup message on discord bot (C#)

Tags: c#, discord

I'm trying to make it so when my discord bot goes online it will post a message in a specific channel.
When I try to run the bot with the command below I just get:

*System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'*

Any help? I know very little about C# so I may just seem stupid.

```
client.ExecuteAndWait(async () =>

        {
            var Chat = client.GetChannel(TheChannelID);

            await Chat.SendMessage("Good morning!");
        });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What version of Discord.NET are you using?

Comment: 0.9.6 I don't know if I should use another verision though.

Comment: I recommend you update to Discord.NET v1.0+ though..

Comment: Ok I'll try doing that.

Comment: I did and now a lot of my code has stopped working and I get a lot of errors.

Comment: The startup guide is located here: https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/guides/getting_started/installing.html , most of the codes in 0.9 wont work in 1.0.